# For some reason it is only displaying one if statement

Tags: python, tkinter

```
        from tkinter import *
import random

easy = ['A','V','M','P','O','E']
random.shuffle(easy)




def raise_frame(frame):
    frame.tkraise()

root = Tk()

f1 = Frame(root)
f2 = Frame(root)
f3 = Frame(root)
f4 = Frame(root)

for frame in (f1, f2, f3, f4):
    frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='news')

Random = Label(f1, text=easy, bg="#00CDCD", font=("Chewy", 20))
Random.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=20)

Entryfield = Entry(f1, font=("Chewy", 22))
Entryfield.pack(pady=105)

Begin = Button(f1, text='Begin', font=("Chewy", 24), bg="#00CDCD",
                  command=lambda: Random.pack_forget() + Begin.pack_forget())
Begin.pack(side="bottom", fill="both")

Submit = Button(f1, text="Submit", bg="#00CDCD", font=("Chewy", 24), command=lambda: winlose())
Submit.pack(fill="x", side="bottom")
```

This statement is only showing incorrect either way when I press submit, I have tried other conditions such as if not and else but still displays the same statement the code only displays the label if I use !=.

```
def winlose():
        if Entryfield == Random:
            Win = ("Your answer was correct")
            tts = Label(f1, text=Win, font=('Chewy', 20), bg="#00CDCD")
            tts.pack()
        else:
            L = ("Your answer is wrong")
            ttr = Label(f1, text=L, font=('Chewy', 20), bg="#00CDCD")
            ttr.pack()


raise_frame(f1)
root.geometry("800x400")
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should replace the line:

```
        if Entryfield == Random:
```

With the line:

```
        if Entryfield.get() == Random['text']:
```

This means that instead of comparing an `Entry` widget and a `Label` widget, you are comparing the text from each of them.

---

Also note that:

```
        from tkinter import *
```

Should be:

```
from tkinter import *
```

(This is obvious, probably just a typo)

---

And that it would probably help you to remove the line:

```
root.geometry("800x400")
```

Without this line, the window will auto-resize to fit all the widgets in.

---

Also that the line:

```
              command=lambda: Random.pack_forget() + Begin.pack_forget())
```

Will raise an error when called, because `lambda` doesn't work like this: you can't just add functions. Instead, I would create a new function:

```
def begin_func():
    Random.pack_forget()
    Begin.pack_forget()
```

And change the line to:

```
              command=begin_func)
```

---

Finally, I assume that you only want the answer to be typeable once `Begin` has been pressed, to achieve this, you should change:

```
Entryfield = Entry(f1, font=("Chewy", 22))
```

To:

```
Entryfield = Entry(f1, font=("Chewy", 22), state=DISABLED)
```

And add the following line to `begin_func`:

```
    Entryfield.config(state=NORMAL)
```

---

All in all, the final code should be:

```
from tkinter import *
import random

easy = ['A','V','M','P','O','E']
random.shuffle(easy)


def raise_frame(frame):
    frame.tkraise()

def begin_func():
    Random.pack_forget()
    Begin.pack_forget()
    Entryfield.config(state=NORMAL)

root = Tk()

f1 = Frame(root)
f2 = Frame(root)
f3 = Frame(root)
f4 = Frame(root)

for frame in (f1, f2, f3, f4):
    frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='news')

Random = Label(f1, text=easy, bg="#00CDCD", font=("Chewy", 20))
Random.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=20)

Entryfield = Entry(f1, font=("Chewy", 22), state=DISABLED)
Entryfield.pack(pady=105)

Begin = Button(f1, text='Begin', font=("Chewy", 24), bg="#00CDCD",
                  command=begin_func)
Begin.pack(side="bottom", fill="both")

Submit = Button(f1, text="Submit", bg="#00CDCD", font=("Chewy", 24), command=lambda: winlose())
Submit.pack(fill="x", side="bottom")
def winlose():
        if Entryfield.get() == Random['text']:
            Win = ("Your answer was correct")
            tts = Label(f1, text=Win, font=('Chewy', 20), bg="#00CDCD")
            tts.pack()
        else:
            L = ("Your answer is wrong")
            ttr = Label(f1, text=L, font=('Chewy', 20), bg="#00CDCD")
            ttr.pack()


raise_frame(f1)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You condition has several problems. If you want to get the text of the entry then you have to use `Entry.get()` and it will return the text. Second you need to get the text of the label to test the equality. For this you can use `Label["text"]` and it will give you the text of the label as `get` method don't works on label. Also remove the spaces between the label text in `if` condition. I have also fixed your code indentation.
Your if condition can be like:`if Entryfield.get() == "".join(Random["text"].split(" ")):`

```
from tkinter import *
import random

easy = ['A','V','M','P','O','E']
random.shuffle(easy)




def raise_frame(frame):
    frame.tkraise()

root = Tk()

f1 = Frame(root)
f2 = Frame(root)
f3 = Frame(root)
f4 = Frame(root)

for frame in (f1, f2, f3, f4):
    frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='news')

Random = Label(f1, text=easy, bg="#00CDCD", font=("Chewy", 20))
Random.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=20)

Entryfield = Entry(f1, font=("Chewy", 22))
Entryfield.pack(pady=105)

Begin = Button(f1, text='Begin', font=("Chewy", 24), bg="#00CDCD",
                  command=lambda: Random.pack_forget() + Begin.pack_forget())
Begin.pack(side="bottom", fill="both")

Submit = Button(f1, text="Submit", bg="#00CDCD", font=("Chewy", 24), command=lambda: winlose())
Submit.pack(fill="x", side="bottom")


def winlose():
    if Entryfield.get() == "".join(Random["text"].split(" ")):
        Win = ("Your answer was correct")
        tts = Label(f1, text=Win, font=('Chewy', 20), bg="#00CDCD")
        tts.pack()
    else:
        L = ("Your answer is wrong")
        ttr = Label(f1, text=L, font=('Chewy', 20), bg="#00CDCD")
        ttr.pack()


raise_frame(f1)
root.geometry("800x400")
root.mainloop()
```